# Sound troubles with the 3.5" spotpear/waveshare touchscreen

Tags: audio, touchscreen, audio-playback

I purchased a 3.5" waveshare/spotpear touchscreen for my Pi. Long story made short, I cobbled together a few different ways of getting it to work consistently. I've described the process [here](https://github.com/mitchpehora/tinyPi/tree/master/waveshare/ss35).

I hit a bit of a snag when I connected the touchscreen and got a error "No ALSA audio devices were detected. Enable the internal audio device, or connect a USB or HAT interface" when I attempted to configure the audio preferences. Same problem when I switched to my HDMI display.

Can anyone help me get audio working? Tried googling around, but couldn't find anything...

Thanks in advance!